# HTML tags are stripped away

Tags: forms

I'm new with Drupal but have to use it to develop a web form for my workplace. I have to insert a `form` in a drupal web page and I am allowed to insert it in full HTML.

However, since I must paste code directly in a little editor box, I have to cut all my CSS code and paste it in a `<style>` tag.

After hitting save, Drupal essentially removes the tag and the form looks horrible. Here is my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
            .column,.columns,.container,.u-full-width{width:100%;box-sizing:border-box}h1,h2,h3{letter-spacing:-.1rem}body,h6{line-height:1.6}.container{position:relative;max-width:960px;margin:0 auto;padding:0 20px}ol,p,ul{margin-top:0}.column,.columns{float:left}@media (min-width:400px){.container{width:85%;padding:0}}html{font-size:62.5%}body{font-size:1.5em;font-weight:400;font-family:Raleway,HelveticaNeue,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#222}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:2rem;font-weight:300}h1{font-size:4rem;line-height:1.2}h2{font-size:3.6rem;line-height:1.25}h3{font-size:3rem;line-height:1.3}h4{font-size:2.4rem;line-height:1.35;letter-spacing:-.08rem}h5{font-size:1.8rem;line-height:1.5;letter-spacing:-.05rem}h6{font-size:1.5rem;letter-spacing:0}@media (min-width:550px){.container{width:80%}.column,.columns{margin-left:4%}.column:first-child,.columns:first-child{margin-left:0}.one.column,.one.columns{width:4.66666666667%}.two.columns{width:13.3333333333%}.three.columns{width:22%}.four.columns{width:30.6666666667%}.five.columns{width:39.3333333333%}.six.columns{width:48%}.seven.columns{width:56.6666666667%}.eight.columns{width:65.3333333333%}.nine.columns{width:74%}.ten.columns{width:82.6666666667%}.eleven.columns{width:91.3333333333%}.twelve.columns{width:100%;margin-left:0}.one-third.column{width:30.6666666667%}.two-thirds.column{width:65.3333333333%}.one-half.column{width:48%}.offset-by-one.column,.offset-by-one.columns{margin-left:8.66666666667%}.offset-by-two.column,.offset-by-two.columns{margin-left:17.3333333333%}.offset-by-three.column,.offset-by-three.columns{margin-left:26%}.offset-by-four.column,.offset-by-four.columns{margin-left:34.6666666667%}.offset-by-five.column,.offset-by-five.columns{margin-left:43.3333333333%}.offset-by-six.column,.offset-by-six.columns{margin-left:52%}.offset-by-seven.column,.offset-by-seven.columns{margin-left:60.6666666667%}.offset-by-eight.column,.offset-by-eight.columns{margin-left:69.3333333333%}.offset-by-nine.column,.offset-by-nine.columns{margin-left:78%}.offset-by-ten.column,.offset-by-ten.columns{margin-left:86.6666666667%}.offset-by-eleven.column,.offset-by-eleven.columns{margin-left:95.3333333333%}.offset-by-one-third.column,.offset-by-one-third.columns{margin-left:34.6666666667%}.offset-by-two-thirds.column,.offset-by-two-thirds.columns{margin-left:69.3333333333%}.offset-by-one-half.column,.offset-by-one-half.columns{margin-left:52%}h1{font-size:5rem}h2{font-size:4.2rem}h3{font-size:3.6rem}h4{font-size:3rem}h5{font-size:2.4rem}h6{font-size:1.5rem}}a{color:#5B0000}a:hover{color:#0FA0CE}.button,button,input[type=submit],input[type=reset],input[type=button]{display:inline-block;height:38px;padding:0 30px;color:#555;text-align:center;font-size:11px;font-weight:600;line-height:38px;letter-spacing:.1rem;text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;background-color:transparent;border-radius:4px;border:1px solid #bbb;cursor:pointer;box-sizing:border-box}.button:focus,.button:hover,button:focus,button:hover,input[type=submit]:focus,input[type=submit]:hover,input[type=reset]:focus,input[type=reset]:hover,input[type=button]:focus,input[type=button]:hover{color:#333;border-color:#888;outline:0}.button.button-primary,button.button-primary,input[type=submit].button-primary,input[type=reset].button-primary,input[type=button].button-primary{color:#FFF;background-color:#660000;border-color:#660000}.button.button-primary:focus,.button.button-primary:hover,button.button-primary:focus,button.button-primary:hover,input[type=submit].button-primary:focus,input[type=submit].button-primary:hover,input[type=reset].button-primary:focus,input[type=reset].button-primary:hover,input[type=button].button-primary:focus,input[type=button].button-primary:hover{color:#FFF;background-color:#5B0000;border-color:#5B0000}input[type=tel],input[type=url],input[type=password],input[type=email],input[type=number],input[type=search],input[type=text],select,textarea{height:38px;padding:6px 10px;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #D1D1D1;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:border-box}input[type=tel],input[type=url],input[type=password],input[type=email],input[type=number],input[type=search],input[type=text],textarea{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;appearance:none}textarea{min-height:65px;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px}input[type=tel]:focus,input[type=url]:focus,input[type=password]:focus,input[type=email]:focus,input[type=number]:focus,input[type=search]:focus,input[type=text]:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{border:1px solid #660000;outline:0}label,legend{display:block;margin-bottom:.5rem;font-weight:600}fieldset{padding:0;border-width:0}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{display:inline}label>.label-body{display:inline-block;margin-left:.5rem;font-weight:400}ul{list-style:circle inside}ol{list-style:decimal inside}ol,ul{padding-left:0}ol ol,ol ul,ul ol,ul ul{margin:1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;font-size:90%}.button,button,li{margin-bottom:1rem}code{padding:.2rem .5rem;margin:0 .2rem;font-size:90%;white-space:nowrap;background:#F1F1F1;border:1px solid #E1E1E1;border-radius:4px}pre>code{display:block;padding:1rem 1.5rem;white-space:pre}td,th{padding:12px 15px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid #E1E1E1}td:first-child,th:first-child{padding-left:0}td:last-child,th:last-child{padding-right:0}fieldset,input,select,textarea{margin-bottom:1.5rem}blockquote,dl,figure,form,ol,p,pre,table,ul{margin-bottom:2.5rem}.u-max-full-width{max-width:100%;box-sizing:border-box}.u-pull-right{float:right}.u-pull-left{float:left}hr{margin-top:3rem;margin-bottom:3.5rem;border-width:0;border-top:1px solid #E1E1E1}.container:after,.row:after,.u-cf{content:"";display:table;clear:both}</style>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="eleven columns">
                        <label>Your Name</label>
                        <input class="u-full-width" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="John Doe" type="text"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="eleven columns">
                        <label>Your E-mail</label>
                        <input class="u-full-width" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@mail.com" type="email"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="eleven columns">
                        <label>Request Description</label>
                        <textarea class="u-full-width" name="job_description" id="job_description" placeholder="Description of your job here" style="height:200px"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="eleven columns">
                        <label>Request Support For</label>
                        <select class="u-full-width" name="purpose" id="purpose">
                            <option value="simulation">Simulation</option>
                            <option value="detector_development">Detector Development</option>
                            <option value="detector_electronics">Detector Electronics</option>
                            <option value="electronics_development">Electronics Development</option>
                            <option value="data_acquisition">Data Aquisition</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="eleven columns">    
                            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_support" value="sub_support">Mechanical</input>
                            <input style="margin-left:10%;" type="checkbox" name="sub_support" value="sub_support">PCB</input>
                            <input style="margin-left:10%;"  type="checkbox" name="sub_support" value="sub_support">Firmware</input>
                            <input style="margin-left:10%;"  type="checkbox" name="sub_support" value="sub_support">DAQ Hardware</input>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <input class="button-primary" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">   
            </form>
```

Also, is there any way I can include PHP code as well?
I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several answers to this. I am assuming that you are using Drupal 7.

1) If this is really what you want to do (not recommended), you'll need to do some work with your text filters (Configuration->Content Authoring->Text Formats). I could go into greater detail here, however..

2) You could simply use the [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). You will need to download it to your modules folder (probably sites/all/modules/contrib) and then enable it. Then you can construct your webform using the webform's UI editor. Finally, you would want to apply your CSS in your theme, not paste it into the editor textarea.

As for the PHP Filter, this is a module you can just turn on and then configure like the other Text Formats (the module is just called "php"). However, I would STRONGLY recommend against it! Certainly do not do this on a production site, it's a pretty big security risk. It also makes it very easy to put code someplace in your content that you later forget about, causing all kinds of headaches when you go to troubleshoot issues. Instead, create your own module. Learn how to use Drupal's function hooks instead. They are one of the reasons Drupal is such a powerful platform.

Good luck!